# Is it true that every algebraic extension $F$ of a field $E$ is generated by adding to $E$ an algebraic element?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Is it true that given a field $E$, any finite algebraic extension $F$ of $E$ is obtained by adding to $E$ a root of some irreducible polynomial over $E$? I know this is true in finite fields but I wonder if it still holds also in general.

EDIT: I added "finite" to algebraic extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you state it, it is false; it is even false for finite fields, as an extension given by a single element can only be finite, but algebraic extensions may be infinite.

The exact statement, in full generality, is due to Artin, generalizing the classical Primitive Element Theorem.

> **Artin's Theorem.** Let $F/E$ be a field extension of finite degree. Then $F=E(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in F$ if and only if there exist only finitely many intermediate fields $K$, $E\subseteq K\subseteq F$.

The classical Primitive Element Theorem, which seems to be what you are alluding to, is that if $F/E$ is finite and separable, then $F=E(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in F$. This applies to the cases where $E$ is a perfect field (so all extensions are separable), which would include all finite fields and all fields of characteristic $0$.

For an example where this does not happen, let $E=\mathbb{F}_p(u,v)$ be the function field on two indeterminates over the finite field of order $p$, and let $F=E(u^{1/p},v^{1/p})$. This extension is not primitive (i.e., given by a single element). To verify this, show that for every $\alpha\in F$, $\alpha^p\in E$. That means every extension of the form $E(\alpha)$ has degree at most $p$ (in fact, $1$ or $p$), but $F$ has degree $p^2$ over $E$.

Comment: I meant finite algebraic extension in my question but I wrote it down badly, sorry. I've just edited it. However your answer is exactly what I was looking for as I didn't know about this Artin's theorem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is not. If $\alpha$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $\mu_\alpha$, then $[E(\alpha):E]=\deg\mu_\alpha$. So such an extension always has finite degree. But not all algebraic extensions have finite degree. For instance, $\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q$, where $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$, does not have finite degree, even though it is algebraic.